# Как реализовать движение рамки вместе с текущей позицией в recycleview?

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: текущий элемент]

[image: следующий за ним элемент]

[image: нажал на кнопку следующий пункт не прокручивая сам список - рамка пропала]

Я пытаюсь добавить рамку к текущему элементу. Для смены вида item используется selector. Selector использую в корневом item следующим образом `android:background="@drawable/selector_item"` При смене текущего элемента рамка тоже должна передвигаться. Она передвигается, только если находится в пределах видимости. Если я вызываю scrollToPosition, когда новый элемент recycle не виден даже краем, то рамка пропадает.

```
            //recycle_color.get(position).constr_item.isSelected = true
            if(position==0)
            {
                recycle_color.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)?.constr_item?.isSelected = false
            }
            else {
                recycle_color.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)?.constr_item?.isSelected = false
            }

            val s1 = recycle_color.adapter?.itemCount
            var indexEl: Int = 0

            var currentFile = ElementCatalog(my_file, false)

            if (position == s1) {
                if (recycle_color.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(positionItem)?.checkBox?.isChecked == true) {
                    indexEl = prod1.indexOf(currentFile)
                    prod1[indexEl].priznak = true

                    myRecycler.apply {
                        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
                        adapter = CustomRecyclerAdapter(prod1, this@MainFragment)
                    }

                    val dialog = DialogFileFragment()
                    dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "custom")
                }
                position = 0
                recycle_color.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)?.constr_item?.isSelected = false
            }
            else {
                position = position + 1
                recycle_color.layoutManager?.findViewByPosition(position)?.constr_item?.isSelected = true
            }
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout4">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycle_color"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="95sp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/ColorItem"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="#4C7286"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="80sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Serial_number_2"
                android:textColor="#4C7286"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Article"
                android:textColor="#4C7286"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="110sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Lot"
                android:textColor="#4C7286"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView18"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/border2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/Weight"
                android:textColor="#4C7286"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle_color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="207dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout3"
            tools:itemCount="2"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Selected background -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_selection_shape"/>
    <!-- Unselected background -->
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@color/colorWhite"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: не очень понятно что у вас происходит, прикрепите картинку какую-то или что-то типа такого, по логике у вас фон элемента списка должен стабильно находится на элементе независимо от действий юзера, вероятнее всего проблема в селекторе

Comment: добавил изображения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил объект

```
    var listPosition = 0

}
```

После чего в реализацию кнопки добавил следующий код

```
position = position + 1
CommonData.listPosition = position
                var itemcount:Int = 0
                if (recycle_color.adapter!=null) {
                    itemcount = recycle_color.adapter?.itemCount!!
                }
                recycle_color.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,itemcount)
                recycle_color.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(position)
```

В адаптер (onBindViewHolder)

```
val view = holder.itemView
        view.isSelected = (position==CommonData.listPosition)
```